# Heuristic argument on Goldbach's conjecture

Tags: number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

If $p$ is prime number $p \not = 2,3$ then $p= \pm 1 \bmod 6$

If $n$ is even:

case I

$n= 0 \bmod 6$

$n=(+1+6 \cdot a)+(-1+6 \cdot b)=p_a+p_b$

$p_a= 1 \bmod 6,p_b= -1 \bmod 6$

case II

$n= 2 \bmod 6$

$n=(+1+6 \cdot a)+(+1+6 \cdot b)=p_a+p_b$

$p_a,p_b= 1 \bmod 6$

and

$n=3+(-1+6 \cdot c)=3+p_c$

$p_c= -1 \bmod 6$

case III

$n= -2 \bmod 6$

$n=(-1+6 \cdot a)+(-1+6 \cdot b)=p_a+p_b$

$p_a,p_b= -1 \bmod 6$

and

$n= 4 \bmod 6=3+(+1+6 \cdot c)=3+p_c$

$p_c= 1 \bmod 6$

**Example case III**

for $ n=100$

In this graph the pairs of numbers $n=p_a+p_b$

$p_a,p_b= -1 \bmod 6$

[image]

Note the symmetry with respect to $n/2$.

and

$n= 3+ 97$

$97= 1 \bmod 6$

**Question**

Considering for example $n= -2 \bmod 6$ with $n-3$ composite. 
Considering that for large values of $n$ the distance between two consecutive primes increases.
Is it possible to say that it is very likely that there is a large $ n $ such that for every prime number $ p $ less than or equal $ n / 2 $ corresponds to a composite number $ (n-p) $?
[image]

Comment: Lots of things are "likely" and even more are "possible". When it comes to a famous long standing unsolved conjecture, the only thing that counts as a disproof is a concrete counter-example, not speculation.

Comment: @Deepak, one could in principle give a non-constructive proof that a counterexample must exist. (One might also give a heuristic argument that a counterexample *should* exist, which is what I think the OP is really asking about here.)

Comment: It is difficult to find a counter example considering a great value of n. Considering that for large values ​​of n the prime ones greater than n / 2 are few compared to those lower than n / 2 graphically it is possible to see that there is a possibility of this happening.

Comment: @BarryCipra The first, by rigorous argument, would count. The latter would be speculation. I think there's already a lot of it surrounding famous problems like this and the Collatz conjecture. Still, the latter (asking about plausibility of a heuristic argument) is a reasonable question, but the title should have been better phrased.

Comment: Goldbach's conjecture is open, so it COULD be false. But the "probability" is almost $0$.

Comment: you forgot at least two cases and this is all known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heuristic arguments don't *prove* anything, but they can provide an indication of what's likely to be true. In this case, heuristic reasoning seems to *favor* Goldbach:

For $n=6k-2$ there are $k$ numbers congruent to congruent to $-1$ mod $6$. Roughly $k/2$ of them are less than $n/2$ and $k/2$ of them are greater than $n/2$. Of the ones less than $n/2$, roughly $(k/2)/\ln(k/2)\approx k/(2\ln k)$ are prime (using $\ln(k/2)=\ln k-\ln2\approx\ln k$ when $k$ is large). For each such prime $p$, the probability that $n-p$ is prime is (very) roughly $1/\ln n\approx1/\ln(6k)\approx1/\ln k$, which means the probability it's composite is (again very) roughly $1-1/\ln k$. This means the probability that $n-p$ is composite for *all* the relevant primes $p$ is (very!) roughly

$$\left(1-{1\over\ln k}\right)^{k/(2\ln k)}=\left(\left(1-{1\over\ln k}\right)^{\ln k}\right)^{k/(2(\ln k)^2)}\approx e^{-k/(2(\ln k)^2}\lt{1\over k^2}$$

so the expected number of counterexamples to Goldbach for numbers of the form $n=6k-2$ with $k\ge K$ (which is easy to make fairly large) is, heuristically, less than

$$\sum_{k=K}^\infty{1\over k^2}\approx{1\over K}$$

The important thing here really is that the series representing the expected number of counterexamples is *convergent*, suggesting that the number of counterexamples is finite.

Comment: This is a very nice answer, but I am not sure to which extend it is possible to be appreciated (after some experience with posts here on Goldbach, Collatz and Co) and whether or not one should even post an answer. But for me this is a great answer.