# If $p$ is the largest prime less than $2n$, what is the probability that $2n-p$ is a prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Let $p$ be the largest prime not exceeding an even number $2n$. I observed that $2n - p$ has a high density of primes and it decrease very slowly. More specifically, for $2n \le 10^6$ the density is $0.6212$ and it drop down to $0.58427$ for $2n \le 3.65 \times 10^{10}$.

**Question 1**: What is the density of primes in the sequence $2n-p$?

**Some observation**: The divisors of $n$ do not divide $2n-p$ for $n \ge 4$. Thus, the  more divisors $n$ has, the more likely it is for $2n-p$ to be a prime. This was observed in the data. Let $a_{n,d}$ be the sequence of positive integers which have $d$ or more divisors. I observed that as $d$ increases, the density of primes in the sequence $2a_{n,d} - p$ increase. Given below are the densities of primes in the first $10^6$ terms of $2a_{n,d} - p$ for different values of $d$.

```
(d, density)
(2, 0.621)
(3, 0.625)
(5, 0.635)
(10, 0.647)
(20, 0.662)
(50, 0.695)
(100, 0.720)
(150, 0.723)
(200, 0.744)
(230, 0.747)
```

Comment: $2n-p$ is odd for $n\ge 2$ and less than the prime gap after $p$ , hence it should be much smaller than $p$ for large $p$ giving a good chance that it is a prime number. $1$ is a rare value, it occurs only if $2n-1$ is prime.

Comment: @Peter If we look at the sequence of natural numbers, the density of primes drops below   $0.43$ when we reach $7$ and it continues to drop further in accordance with the PNT. But in this question, the density is hovering around $0.58$ even for $n$ in the neighborhood of $10^{10}$. So there must be something else stronger than the fact the $2n-p$ is small which is driving this high density.

Comment: The largest prime gap until $p=10^{10}$ is $354$. $2n-p$ must be smaller and odd.  Moreover , apart from a few small cases we have $\gcd(2n-p,n)=1$. So, if for example , $3\mid n$, $3\nmid 2n-p$. Already ruling out prime factor $3$ gives a number not exceeding $354$ a good chance to be prime.

Comment: With $g(p_k)=p_{k+1}-p_k-1$ it is $=\frac1x \sum_{p\le x} (\pi(g(p))-1) \gg \frac1x\sum_{p\le x} \frac{g(p)}{\log g(p)} \gg \frac1x\sum_{p\le x} \frac{\log p}{\log \log p} \gg \frac1{\log \log x}$

Comment: @NilotpalSinha A better thing to compare to is the density of (odd) primes among odd natural numbers, since we know $2n-p$ is odd. This stays at least at $0.5$ all the way through $101$ (which is as far as I looked). It's above $0.6$ for $7$ up until $29$. Together with Peter's observation that prime gaps are still pretty small, this resembles a weighted average of that particular kind of prime density. And even at $10^{10}$, prime gaps are not large enough to weight in averaging lower density values.

Comment: I would like to say if $n$ goes to infinity, this goes to zero... the gaps are "averagely" tending to infinity and when the gaps larger, the possibility of primes will be smaller.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527085/heuristic-argument-on-goldbachs-conjecture/3527447#3527447

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to say that this probability to goes to zero if $n$ goes to inifity... and the speed, I guess, will be REALLY SLOW.

Let $\pi(n)$ to be the number of primes smaller than $n$. Let $m=\pi(2n)$ and denote $g_{m}=2n-p_m$ Let the gaps $g_t$ to be $p_{t+1}-p_t$ for $t\le m-1$, where $p_{t}$ is the $t$th prime.  We can use binomial coefficients to proof that $\pi(n)<\frac{10n}{\ln n}$. This is a really rough bound, but it is enough. Let $m=\pi(2n)$ and denote $g_{m}=2n-p_m$.

Now consider the $2n$'s between $p_k$ to $p_{k+1}$ for $k\ge 2$. So the $2n-p_k$ between them will be $1,3,\dots,p_{k+1}-p_k-1$, and at most $\pi(p_{k+1}-p_k)\le 10 g_k/\ln g_k$ primes inside them.

So the total number of even $l\le n$ such that $l$ minus the largest prime small then $l$ is also a prime will be $\le \sum_{i=1}^m 10g_i/\ln g_i$.

Notice that $f(x)=10x/\ln x$ is a concave function when $x\ge 8$. So it is largest when some of them are equal, and others are $2,4,6$. So we can over estimate them: $m$ of them are $2$, $m$ of them are $4$, $m$ of them are $6$, and the else are averaged by $m$ numbers with the total sum of $2n$. So we have:

$$\sum_{i=1}^m 10g_i/\ln g_i \le 10m(2/\ln 2+4/\ln 4+6/\ln 6)+10m(2n/m)/\ln (2n/m)\le 120m+20n/\ln(n/m)\le 2400n/\ln n+20n/\ln(0.1\ln n)\le 2400n/\ln n +200n/\ln \ln  n$$ if $n\ge20$.

Therefore, the probability is upper bounded by $\frac{2400}{\ln n}+\frac{200}{\ln \ln n}$, which tends to zero if $n\to\infty$.