# Why is there an unexpected increase in the density of certain types of Goldbach primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, divisibility

**Note**: [Posted in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416521/why-is-there-an-unexpected-increase-in-the-density-of-certain-types-of-goldbach) since it is unanswered in MSE.

I was checking how quickly we can verify Goldbach's conjecture for a given even number $n$ and it was clear that backward starting from the largest prime below $n$ was much faster than a forward search starting from the small odd prime $3$. I observed the following interesting phenomenon.

Let $n$ be an even number and $p$ be the largest prime less than $n$ such that $n-p$ is also a prime. Let $p_k$ be the $k$-th prime. Then, $p_{\pi(n)-2}$, $p_{\pi(n)-1}$ and $p_{\pi(n)}$ are the three largest primes preceding $n$. Now $p$ can either be the largest prime below $n$, or the prime just before the largest prime or the prime before that and so on. Accordingly, we define:

- $d_1$ is the density of $n$ such that $p = p_{\pi(n)}$
- $d_2$ is the density of $n$ such that $p = p_{\pi(n)-1}$
- $d_3$ is the density of $n$ such that $p = p_{\pi(n)-2}$

Data for $n \le 3 \times 10^{10}$ shows that $d_1$ and $d_2$ decreased as $n$ increased. This was intuitively expected as explained in the answer for the related question "[If $p$ is the largest prime less than $2n$, what is the probability that $2n-p$ is a prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4358961/if-p-is-the-largest-prime-less-than-2n-what-is-the-probability-that-2n-p)". However, quite counter intuitively, $d_3$ increased with $n$ as shown in the graphs below.

**Question 1**: Why does $d_3$ increase with $n$ while $d_1$ and $d_2$ decreased?

**Question 2**: What is the limiting value of $d_3$? Since $d_3 < 1$ and is increasing, it must converge to a positive limiting value.

**Note**: I have not computed $d_k$ for $k \ge 4$ so I do not know if this increasing trend is observed other values of $k$.

**Graphs in normal scale**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Graphs in $\log n$ scale**
[image]

[image]

[image]

**SageMath code**

```
n = 4
target = step = 10^6
i = c1 = c2 = c3 = 0

while True:
    i = i + 1
    p = previous_prime(n)
    if is_prime(n-p) == True:
        c1 = c1 + 1
    else:
        p = previous_prime(p)
        if is_prime(n-p) == True:
            c2 = c2 + 1
        else:
            p = previous_prime(p)
            if is_prime(n-p) == True:
                c3 = c3 + 1
        
    if i >= target:
        print(i, c1, c2, c3, c1/i.n(), c2/i.n(), c3/i.n(), (c1+c2+c3)/i.n())
        target = target + step
    n = n + 2
```

Comment: Can you make plot the same data with a logarithmic scale on the x-axis? I could imagine that only d_1 is decreasing for all x, all the other ones are first increasing and then decreasing, but you don't see the increasing part for d_2 on your plot because it happens on the first 3 or 5 pixels and haven't reached the max of d_3 at 3E+10 yet.

Comment: @quarague I have added the graphs with $\log n$ in the X-axis. The observation however remains the same with only $d_3$ increasing while $d_1$ and $d_2$ decreasing.

Comment: It seems to me that $d_3$ is only increasing *because* $d_1$ and $d_2$ are decreasing.  That is, when $n$ is small, it's rare for $p$ to equal $p_{\pi(n)-2}$, because usually either $n - p_{\pi(n)}$ or $n - p_{\pi(n)-1}$ is prime.  When $n$ is larger, it's more common for neither of the first two to be prime.  And when $n$ is *much* larger, $d_3$ should decrease again and tend towards $0$, because large primes tend to be spaced out more.

Comment: Two ways to test my suspicions:  (1) calculate the densities $d_1$, $d_2$, and $d_3$ where you only consider much larger values of $n$ (maybe 100+ digits, using next_probable_prime if necessary).  (2) redo your calculations, keeping track of the densities of $n$ such that $n - p_{\pi(n) - i}$ is prime, regardless of whether it's the first one.  (If my explanation is right, all the graphs here should decrease at very similar rates.)

Comment: @RaviFernando I running a program for $200$+ digits only numbers. Will update the results after a few hours of run.